# RVM Ruby Default not working

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

Ok so first off I've seen almost all if not all the posts on this here and nothing has worked. Furthermore I don't know how but I have got this to work on a different environment which is basically a clone of my  current set up. I just can't pin point what's different between the two.

**Issue**:
I have `ruby-2.5.0` set as my default but on each new terminal session I get reverted back to `ruby-2.3.3`

So here's my RVM list

```
=> ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

2.5.0 set as my default, in my other env I simply ran

```
rvm use 2.5.0 --default
```

and I'd get 2.5.0 whenever I started a new session. That's not working here.

[HERE](https://gist.github.com/AlphaDaniel/7fcfd40095ac632a76b9fd973cedcc1b) is a gist with my bashrc, bash_profile, and zshrc files.

Comment: What shell do you use? It makes not much sense to share both `.zshrc` and `.bashrc` since they are literally mutually exclusive.

Comment: shell is bash.....  also I haven't been exposed to this stuff yet (student) so pardon my nievete.. I added those because they were mentioned at some point in all the posts I've come across thought better share more then less

Answer (score 0):

Got it working running these 2 commands

```
$ rvm alias create default 2.5.0

$ rvm default 2.5.0
```